# Certificate fail in wss websocket in VPS over Windows. (TLS handshake error)

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, websocket

We have a VPS in Azure, I'm using websocket-sharp to create a server. I need to connect from web https so I need Secure Connection wss, I created a personal test certificate and I have exported it to ".cer", it I added on web socket in the /bin/debug/theCertificate.cer path on project. I add it as follows:

```
var wssv = new HttpServer(46443, true);
wssv.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(myPath + "/theCertificate.cer", "password");
```

In local server works correctly but at the time of putting in the VPS shows this error:

```
PM|Fatal|WebSocket.connect|WebSocketSharp.WebSocketException: An error has occurred during a TLS handshake. 
  ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. 
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) 
  at Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBe 
  foreNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) 
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) 
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthenticati on(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) 
  at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtoco ls enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.setClientStream()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.setClientStream()
  at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.doHandshake()
  at WebSocketSharp.WebSocket.connect()
```

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks.

***The solution:*** The problem was that we needed to enable SslProtocols, and also what @vtortola commented. Thanks and good luck.

```
wssv.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols
```

Comment: is the same certificate used for HTTPS and WSS?

Comment: Hi! @vtortola, Yes, the certificates were different, when using the same one was solved another error: `failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled` Thank you for the advice.